# How to Prevent Users from opening other pages without login

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

It is Login Page Code which is accepting Username and Password. But other pages are also opening with URL. Used Session Start Also. Please help me with modifications in code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");

    $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "Invalid username or password!";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) (i.e. none at all) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: in a nutshell, any page that requires a user to be logged in to view, then you need to include the require session statement in every page that you want only logged in users to view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you suggest some better tutorial to make login code perfect ?